# Can we create auxiliary constructor in Scala with List?

Tags: scala

I am trying to create a Request object where I can get a single String as input or a list of String as Input. I tried to look through various answers but I don't think I have found any use of List in constructor.
I am trying to do something like this.

```
class GetRequest(val url: String) {

def this(val urlList: List[String]){

 }
}
```

Is it something to do with List's immutability?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scala enforces to have one main constructor and as much as you need 
auxiliary constructors. There's a rule: each constructor must invoke one of the previously defined constructors.

This should work for you:

```
class GetRequest(val urlList: List[String]) {
  def this(url: String) {
    this(List(url))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An auxiliary constructor isn't really necessary when making a distinction between a single passed parameter and a collection of the same type. That's what the varargs syntax is for.

```
class GetRequest(val urls: String*)

new GetRequest("s")
new GetRequest("a","b","c")
new GetRequest(List("x","y","z"):_*)
```

In the constructor code `urls` can be treated as a `Seq[String]` of zero or more elements.